# Why do programming languages not allow spaces in identifiers?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design

This may seem like a dumb question, but still I don't know the answer.

Why do programming languages not allow spaces in the names ( for instance method names )?

I understand it is to facilitate ( allow ) the parsing, and at some point it would be impossible to parse anything if spaces were allowed.

Nowadays we are so use to it that the *norm* is not to see spaces.

For instance:

```
 object.saveData( data );
 object.save_data( data )
 object.SaveData( data );
 [object saveData:data];
```

etc.

Could be written as:

```
 object.save data( data )  // looks ugly, but that's the "nature" way.
```

If it is only for parsing, I guess the identifier could be between `.` and `(` of course, procedural languages wouldn't be able to use it because there is no '.'  but OO do..

I wonder if parsing is the *only* reason, and if it is, how important it is ( I assume that it will be and it will be impossible to do it otherwise, unless all the programming language designers just... forget the option )

**EDIT**

I'm ok with identifiers in general ( as the fortran example ) is bad idea.  Narrowing to OO languages and specifically to methods, I don't see ( I don't mean there is not ) a reason why it should be that way. After all  the `.` and the first `(` may be used.

And forget the `saveData` method , consider this one:

```
key.ToString().StartsWith("TextBox")
```

as:

```
key.to string().starts with("textbox");
```

Comment: This would be about as annoying as having to deal with spaces in filenames. In other words, very.

Comment: @Oscar: saveData( data ) is redundantly named; save( data ) would suffice. See also: method overloading.

Comment: @Dave: Think about any other method name forget about that one.

Comment: @Greg: Yeap, but that's a deficiency from the computers, not of the humans, I mean, we hate it ( me included ) so much, because the computer makes it hard for us, and not because that's the way I name things.

Comment: The problem with spaces isn't just with computer parsing.  An equally large problem is that your final example clearly represents three values; `keys.to`, `string().starts`, and `with("textbox")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the interpreter or compiler can build a parse tree, it must perform lexical analysis,  turning the stream of characters into a stream of tokens. Consider how you would want the following parsed:

a = 1.2423 / (4343.23 * 2332.2);

And how your rule above would work on it. Hard to know how to lexify it without understanding the meaning of the tokens. It would be really hard to build a parser that did lexification at the same time.

Comment: +1. Wouldn't my token be `save data` because it is between a `.` and a `(` What about the other way around? I know compilers have no problem with: `a=1.2423/(4343.23*2332.2);a=a+a;` ( no spaces at all )

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single token. It could well be parsed as two different tokens, and then the parser looks at the context and figures out if those together should form a single name. Depending on the grammar of the language, it may even be unambiguous. So not really an implementation issue.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you do not need to perform lexical analysis to parse code. Just because it's the norm to do so does not mean it is necessary. (Also, lexical analysis CAN simply lex each character as its own token. Useless, but still a "lexer". Also (again), lexers do not need to discard whitespace.)

Comment: I see no problem with lexing alphanumeric characters separately from punctuation.

Answer (score 53):

Be cause i twoul d makepa rsing suc hcode reallydif ficult.

Comment: +1 for making me laugh and giving the correct answer at the same time XD

Comment: Ironically most people had no problem parsing this text.

Bad example. :P

Comment: Yesparsingiseasierwithoutspaces. AndWeAre usedToIt, but_as_a_side_effect. :(

Comment: This is the first time I upvoted an answer that is, IMO, wrong.

Answer (score 14):

I used an implementation of [ALGOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68) (c. 1978) which—extremely annoyingly—required quoting of what is now known as *reserved words*, and allowed spaces in identifiers:

```
  "proc" filter = ("proc" ("int") "bool" p, "list" l) "list":
     "if" l "is" "nil" "then" "nil"
     "elif" p(hd(l)) "then" cons(hd(l), filter(p,tl(l)))
     "else" filter(p, tl(l))
     "fi";
```

Also, FORTRAN (the capitalized form means F77 or earlier), was more or less insensitive to spaces.  So this could be written:

```
  799 S = FLO AT F (I A+I B+I C) / 2 . 0
      A  R E  A = SQ R T ( S *(S - F L O ATF(IA)) * (S - FLOATF(IB)) *
     +     (S - F LOA TF (I C)))
```

which was syntactically identical to

```
  799 S = FLOATF (IA + IB + IC) / 2.0
      AREA = SQRT( S * (S - FLOATF(IA)) * (S - FLOATF(IB)) *
     +     (S - FLOATF(IC)))
```

With that kind of history of abuse, why make parsing difficult for humans?  Let alone complicate computer parsing.

Comment: Not to mention: DO 10 I = 1.10 (an assignment) and DO 10 I = 1,10 (the start of a DO loop).

Comment: It's actually a requirement of Algol spec. It always allowed whitespace in identifiers (but at the same time ignored it, so `foo bar(x)` was the same as `foobar(x)`), and required that keywords and identifiers are in different "namespaces", so implementation had to quote either one or the other.

Comment: The point made in this answer is moot; any language construct could be "abused". Hell I could my entire library have fUnCtIonNaMes() like that that's totally unreadable. In practice no one does that so using that as an argument is rather pointless. (You never see array access being done as foo["bar"]; in C.) As for the parsing; no additional difficulties are brought upon as a result of whitespace so long a few simple rules are added (like reserved keywords remain untouched).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's the parsing - both human and computer.  It's easier to read and easier to parse if you can safely assume that whitespace doesn't matter.  Otherwise, you can have potentially ambiguous statements, statements where it's not clear how things go together, statements that are hard to read, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Such a change would make for an ambiguous language in the best of cases. For example, in a C99-like language:

```
if not foo(int x) {
    ...
}
```

is that equivalent to:

1. A function definition of `foo` that returns a value of type `ifnot`:

   ```
   ifnot foo(int x) {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. A call to a function called `notfoo` with a variable named `intx`:

   ```
   if notfoo(intx) {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. A negated call to a function called `foo` (with C99's `not` which means `!`):

   ```
   if not foo(intx) {
       ...
   }
   ```

This is just a small sample of the ambiguities you might run into.

**Update:** I just noticed that obviously, in a C99-like language, the condition of an `if` statement would be enclosed in parentheses. Extra punctuation can help with ambiguities if you choose to ignore whitespace, but your language will end up having lots of extra punctuation wherever you would normally have used whitespace.

Comment: And you would also need a whole lot of lookahead to realize that it is not a call to a function called "if not foo".

Comment: I disagree, it doesn't make parsing any more difficult at all. A simple rule that makes it clear that reserved keywords take precedence (as "non-concatenatable" tokens) solves that issue.

Comment: @Wiz: In languages which disallow spaces in identifiers, it is generally legal to include a reserved word as *part* of an identifier provided the identifier doesn't completely match the word; accidentally specifying a reserved word as an identifier will generally yield code which won't compile, rather than code which compiles but with an unintended meaning.  Having reserved words be recognized when they appear within an identifier, would create many more possibilities for trouble, especially if any new words are ever added to the language.

Comment: @supercat my comment was toward the ambiguity issue. Spaces are not a problem to deal with given there are proper grammar rules in place. I've purposely neglected the whole programmer aspect of it which would, as you pointed out, easily cause a lot of headache. However, strictly speaking, as far as the language itself is concerned, it's not really a problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few languages which allow spaces in identifiers. The fact that nearly all languages constrain the set of characters in identifiers is because parsing is more easy and most programmers are accustomed to the compact no-whitespace style.

I don’t think there’s real reason.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a language?  I think it would be interesting to take a look at.

Comment: Algol-60 (and Simula, as a superset of of it) was one such. ABC (http://ftp.cwi.nl/abc/examples/advent/advent.ftp) allowed it in function names (e.g. `TRY TO TAKE object` or `INCLUDE object IN property FOR thing` - uppercased identifiers are all parts of function name, and lowercase ones are parameter names).

Comment: Another example would be AppleScript which allows it for some identifiers.

Comment: Inform 7 allows multiple-word names. It's bad; you can't tell if a phrase is just a variable name or if the individual English words actually take their English meanings.

Comment: SQL allows spaces in identifiers if they are quoted. (But not keywords) `select "A COLUMN" from "A TABLE"`

Comment: Pogoscript: https://github.com/featurist/pogoscript#examples

Answer (score 4):

Check out Stroustrup's classic [Generalizing Overloading for C++2000](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

We were allowed to put spaces in filenames back in the 1960's, and computers **still** don't handle them very well (everything used to break, then most things, now it's just a few things - but they still break).

We simply can't wait another 50 years before our code will work again.
:-)

(And what everyone else said, of course. In English, we use spaces and punctuation to separate the words. The same is true for computer languages, except that computer parsers define "words" in a slightly different sense)

Comment: Fundamentally different. Spaces in filenames must be supported by all programs that might access those files. Spaces in a programming language's identifiers must be supported only by the tools for compiling or running that language.

Answer (score 1):

Using space as part of an identifier makes parsing really murky (is that a syntactic space or an identifier?), but the same sort "natural reading" behavior is achieved with keyword arguments. `object.save(data: something, atomically: true)`

Answer (score 1):

The `TikZ` language for creating graphics in `LaTeX` allows whitespace in parameter names (also known as 'keys'). For instance, you see things like

```
\shade[
  top color=yellow!70,
  bottom color=red!70,
  shading angle={45},
]
```

In this restricted setting of a comma-separated list of key-value pairs, there's no parsing difficulty. In fact, I think it's much easier to read than the alternatives like `topColor`, `top_color` or `topcolor`.